# When to index with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, indexing, mongoose

So I understand that indexing makes queries faster but I don't understand how to determine what should and shouldn't be indexed. For example I was looking at this

```html
var FavoriteSchema = new Schema({
 user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
        index: true,
    },
    business: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Business',
        required: true,
        index: true,
    },
    isDeleted: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            default: false,
    },
```

I noticed that user and business has index:true but isDeleted does not, but why? I also would like to know how is indexing in this way speeding up a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation:

> Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect.

Read more here:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/

Are you going to query the collection for documents with a specific user id? Probably yes, so you should create index for that.

Are you going to query the collection for documents with a specific `isDeleted` value? If yes, create index for that. If no, or only sometimes, then don't create the index.

Comment: when I follow your reference I see index created like this: collection.createIndex( { <key and index type specification> } but using mongoose I just say index:true
are they both doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes :) From mongoose docs: “When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls createIndex for each defined index in your schema.”